# Apache Flink - custom java options are not recognized inside job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've added the following line to flink-conf.yaml:

env.java.opts: "-Ddy.props.path=/PATH/TO/PROPS/FILE"

when starting jobmanager (jobmanager.sh start cluster) I see in logs that the jvm option is indeed recognized

```
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  JVM Options:
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xms256m
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xmx256m
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Ddy.props.path=/srv/dy/stream-aggregators/aggregators.conf
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog.file=/srv/flink-1.2.0/log/flink-flink-jobmanager-0-flinkvm-master.log
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/srv/flink-1.2.0/conf/log4j.properties
2017-02-20 12:19:23,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/srv/flink-1.2.0/conf/logback.xml
```

but when I run a flink job (flink run -d PROG.JAR), System.getProperty("dy.props.path") returns null (and when printing the system properties, I see that it is indeed absent.)

The question really is - how do I set system properties that will be available inside of the flink-job's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very much connected with the runtime architecture of Flink [[1]](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/concepts/runtime.html).

I understand you're running your job in a standalone cluster. Remember that the `JobManager` and the `TaskManager`s run in separate jvm instances. You have to consider where each block of code will be executed.

For instance, the code in transformations like `map` or `filter` is executed on the `TaskManager`.
The Code in the `main` method of your entry class is executed in the command line tool `flink`, which of course does not have the system property set, as it spawns a temporary(-d) jvm just for the job submission.

If you submit your job through `WebUI` the code from your `main` method is executed on the `JobManager` so the property will be set then.

In general I would rather discourage passing the program arguments through the system properties as it is a bad practice.

---

Below you have a simple example:

I started:

- a `JobManager` with `env.java.opts:"-Ddy.props.path=jobmanager"`
- a `TaskManager` with `env.java.opts:"-Ddy.props.path=taskmanager"`

The code of my job looks following:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val stream = env.fromCollection(1 to 4)

    val prop = System.getProperty("dy.props.path")
    stream.map(_ => System.getProperty("dy.props.path") + "  mainArg: " + prop).print()

    env.execute("stream")
  }
}
```

When I submit the code through `flink` tool the output is as follows:

```
taskmanager  mainArg: null
taskmanager  mainArg: null
taskmanager  mainArg: null
taskmanager  mainArg: null
```

When it is submitted through the `WebUI` I get:

```
taskmanager  mainArg: jobmanager
taskmanager  mainArg: jobmanager
taskmanager  mainArg: jobmanager
taskmanager  mainArg: jobmanager
```

Comment: So how do you submit a job via command line with jvm options to the fork jvm ? I see options for yarn but how about standalone cluster ?

Comment: In the standalone cluster the taskmanagers must be spawned up front, before submitting the job. You can set the jvm options when starting taskmanagers.