# Apache Flink WebUI Set Environment Variables

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am using flink-docker 1.4.0 and I have created a scala job to be run on Flink. The job uses typesafe config which looks similar to that :

```
servers = "localhost:9092"
servers = ${?KAFKA_SERVERS}
```

The problem is that it works perfectly, if I set the `KAFKA_SERVERS` in the docker-compose file starting the jobmanager and taskmanager. 
But I would like to set them from WebUI using Program Arguments.
I have tried to add `env.java.opts="-DKAFKA_SERVERS=192.168.99.100:9092` like in 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U53wj.png).But it is not visible inside jar. Is there a way to set environment variables per job in Flink WebUI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work since TaskManager's JVM machines are spawned before submitting your job and job is executed inside those JVMs, thus you can not pass environment variables in that way. The box where you put `env.java.opts="-DKAFKA_SERVERS=192.168.99.100:9092"` is even called "Program options" (`args` passed to your `main` function).

This answer provides more detailed explanation to this:
[Apache Flink - custom java options are not recognized inside job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344624/apache-flink-custom-java-options-are-not-recognized-inside-job/42558319#42558319)
and suggests solution:

Do not relay on environment variables when spawning your job.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set environment variables per job only.

Flink cluster consists of Taskmanagers and Jobmanagers which are jvm processes. Submitting a job does not spawn any new jvm processes therefore you can only set env variables clusterwise.

You can try to pass this argument as command line argument.